# Load and display text file in javascript without user input

Tags: input, text, upload

I need to pass the name of a file with querystring and use it to load and display tat file. I want to do it without user input.

I have tried the following to automatically fill in an input-file field (which works) but then I want to use tat input to display the text. I have tried calling a separate function to do that but it doesn't work. My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reading file</title>
   </head>
<body>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()" />
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="previewFile()"/>
<script>
    const filename = "textfile.txt" // simulate a querystring
    // Get a reference to our file input
    const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

    // Create a new File object
    const myFile = new File(['Hello World!'], filename, {
        type: 'text/plain',
        lastModified: new Date(),
    });

    // Now let's create a DataTransfer to get a FileList
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.items.add(myFile);
    fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
    previewFile();

</script>
<script>
function previewFile() {
  const content = document.querySelector('.content');
  const [file] = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').file;
  const reader = new FileReader();

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```